# Закрытие потока Delphi

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Имеется прога которая подрубается к серваку, и в потоке читает всё что ей пришлет сервак. Если сервер закрывает соединение, то потоку отправляется сообщение по которому он выходит из бесконечного цикла, отправляет сообщение главному окну о своём завершении, закрывается, главное окно вызывает **Destroy** класса, который и создаёт поток. Проблема возникает когда инициатором закрытия выступает главное окно, оно вызывает **Destroy** класса который и создаёт поток, в коде **Destroy** потоку также отправляется сообщение о том что пора закрываться, но ответа не приходит, а сам поток иногда завершается, иногда нет. В чем проблема?

Код потока

```
procedure TClientTCP.TTestThread.Execute;
var
    ARecvText: string;
    ARecvChar: Char;
     msg: TMsg;
begin
  while (true) do begin{основной бесконечный цикл}
  ARecvText:='';
    while (true) do{пока есть что считывать читаем}
        begin
          If Recv(SockStream, ARecvChar, 1, 0)>0 then //читаем по 1-му
            begin
            ARecvText := ARecvText + ARecvChar; {добавляем в строку}
            if ARecvChar =#0 then break ;
          end
          else  break;
        end;

    if length(ARecvText)>0 then{выделяем память на пакет, пропуская случайные разрывы}
        begin
          SetLength(TempBufRead.SBufRead, Length(ARecvText));
          TempBufRead.SBufRead:= ARecvText;
          New(TempBufRead.PointTo);
          TempBufRead:= TempBufRead.PointTo;
          TempBufRead.PointTo:=nil;
          inc(FCheckerPackage);
          PostMessage(FHandle, WM_TCPCLASSMESSAGE,2,0);{отправим сообщение что пришел пакет}
        end;

   if PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then{вот здесь читаем есть ли команда на выход}
      case msg.message of
         WM_TESTTHREAD: begin
          if msg.wParam=1 then shutdown(SockStream, SD_BOTH);{если есть флаг, что это сервак инициатор шатдауним сокет}
          break;{и если есть выскакиваем из цикла}
         end;
      end;
    Self.suspend;{прочитали сообщение, засыпаем}
  end;
  PostMessage( FHandle, WM_TCPCLASSMESSAGE,1,0);{отправляем главному окну сообщение о завершении}
end;
```

Код при котором инициатор закрытия сервак

```
procedure TClientTCP.WMSocketMessage(var Msg: TSockMessage);
begin
  if Msg.Socket <> FSocket then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Внутренняя ошибка программы - неверный сокет', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  if Msg.SockError <> 0 then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Ошибка при взаимодействии с сервером'#13#10 + GetError(Msg.SockError), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  case Msg.SockEvent of
    FD_READ:{Получено сообщение от сервера}
        if FRead.Suspended then FRead.Resume;{будим поток для чтения}

    FD_CLOSE:{сервер закрыл соединение}
      begin
        PostThreadMessage(FRead.ThreadID, WM_TESTTHREAD,1,0);{посылаем сообщение потоку что надо закрываться}
        FRead.Resume;{выводим поток с паузы}
      end;
    else
      begin
        MessageDlg('Внутренняя ошибка программы - неизвестное событие ' + IntToStr(Msg.SockEvent), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Главное окно по клику просто вызывает **Destroy** класса, который и создает поток

```
procedure TForm1.ConnectBtnClick(Sender: TObject);{клик по кнопке закрытия соединения}
 begin
 if Connected then begin
    Connected:=false;
    TcpCon.Disconnect;
 end

procedure TClientTCP.Disconnect;{процедура дисконнекта}
begin
    closesocket(FSocket);
    FSocket := 0;
    Destroy;
end;

destructor TClientTCP.Destroy;
begin
  PostThreadMessage(FRead.ThreadID, WM_TESTTHREAD,0,0);{отправляем в поток что пора закрываться}
  FRead.Resume;{будим поток}
  FRead.Free;
      //отдадим обратно прием сообщений
      FWinOwner.WindowProc := FOldProc;
      FWinOwner.Refresh;
      inherited Destroy;
    end;
```

код реакции формы на сообщения

```
procedure TForm1.WMTcpClassMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
   case Msg.WParam of
   0: begin
      Connected:=true;
      ConnectBtn.Caption:='l';
      StatusEdit.Text:='Подключено к '+SettingForm.AdressEdit.Text;
      ConnectBtn.Enabled:=true;
      SentBtn.Enabled:=true;
      end;
   1: begin{вот это реакция на сообщение о том что поток вышел с цикла и сейчас закроется}
      ConnectBtn.Enabled:=true;
      SentBtn.Enabled:=false;
      ConnectBtn.Caption:='k';
      if Connected then TcpCon.Destroy;{если событие вызвано сервером, то флаг Connect будет в true, если с кнопки то уже Flase, а значит там был Disconnect который уже вызывал Destroy}
      Connected:=false;
      StatusEdit.Text:='Сервер разорвал соединение';
      end;
   2: StatusEdit.Text:='Получено сообщение';
   3: begin StatusEdit.Text:='Подключение не удалось';
      ConnectBtn.Enabled:=true;
      SentBtn.Enabled:=false;
      end;
   4: StatusEdit.Text:='Буфер входящих сообщений пуст';
   5: StatusEdit.Text:='Отключаемся';
   end;

end;
```

Так вот когда сервак вызывает цепь событий уничтожения потока, всё проходит прекрасно, но когда с кнопки то главное окно сообщения о том, что поток вылетел из цикла и закрывается, не получает... по крайней мере уж точно на него никак не реагирует, а поток закрывается "раз через раз", смотрел по отладчику и в мониторе ресурсов количество потоков.

Answer (score 2):

1. Для уничтожения объектов нужно вызывать метод `Free`, а не `Destroy`. Обязательно.
2. `FreeOnTerminate` должен быть `False`.
3. Для корректного уничтожения потока нужно дождаться пока он корректно завершит свое выполнение. Для этого, в вашем случае, достаточно будет в месте, где уничтожается поток, добавить между `FRead.Resume` и `FRead.Free` приведенный ниже код.

Как-то так:

```
FRead.Resume;{будим поток}
FRead.WaitFor; // ждем завершения потока
FRead.Free;
```

Comment: У потока нет `Destroy`, вызывается `Destroy` класса создавшего поток. А `WaitFor` во время разработки не ставлю чтоб как раз получать зависающую программу и искать причину неправильного завершения потока, правильный поток всегда самостоятельно должен нормально завершиться.

Comment: @Сергей, у потока обязательно есть `Destroy`, он есть у любого объекта, просто вы его не переопределяете. Довольно странный у вас подход к отладке. Уничтожение потока с `if not Suspended then WaitFor` самый правильный способ. Загляните в деструктор `TThread`. Правильный поток завершиться должен самостоятельно, но не уничтожиться.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. У потока было `FreeOnTerminate:=True;` таким образом, поток успевал разрушиться раньше чем дойдет до `Free`.
Убрал `FreeOnTerminate:=True;`, `Free` перенес в  `Destroy`, а сообщение о том что пора заканчивать в `Disconnect`. Таким образом когда сервак инициирует разрыв, это же событие отправляет сообщение потоку о том чтоб тот закончил свои дела, затем вызывается `Destroy` в котором `Free` не вызывает проблем так как потоку уже было отправлено сообщение о закрытии. Когда же мы сами инициируем закрытие то вызывается `Disconnect`, которой отправляет сообщение потоку о закрытии, затем вызывается `Destroy` в котором мы освобождаем поток `Free`.

Comment: Самоуничтожение объекта - не очень красивое решение (мягко говоря). Можете легко напороться на AV при неаккуратном обращении с объектом. У `TThread` возможность самоуничтожения добавлена для случая "запустил и забыл", т.е. когда на созданный поток у вас нигде не хранится ссылок и всё общение с ним происходит опосредственно, через сообщения/события. Как только вы начинаете хранить ссылку на объект (потока или вашего `TClientTCP`) самоуничтожение объекта недопустимо.

Comment: @zed `при неаккуратном обращении с объектом` - так обращаться с ним надо аккуратно и проблем не будет)

Comment: Звучит как *"Ходить по граблям надо аккуратно и проблем не будет"*. Оно конечно можно, чтобы жизнь мёдом не казалась, но не нужно.